# don't know how to Implement SSL to PHP with IIS

Tags: php, ssl, iis-7.5

First of all, this is my website link : https://jitsugen.info

Second, this is my phpInfo : https://jitsugen.info/test.php

When i access my site with SSL, this message pop up to google chrome

> The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected either high-risk insecure content on the page or problems with the site’s certificate. Don’t enter sensitive information on this page. Invalid certificate or other serious https issues could indicate that someone is attempting to tamper with your connection to the site.

May i know what should i do to encrypt all information transaction inside php ? my environment is window but not apache, there is not much of information for IIS ;(

Thx for guide =D

Comment: Your site appears to work fine for me (Firefox 4 on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Your homepage is loading a lot of content from non-HTTPS pages (multiple style sheets, external javascript, images, etc...). Unless ALL the content on an HTTPS page is loaded from HTTPS sources, you're going to get warnings.

In particular:

```
<link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

in the page header, and

```
<img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
```

further down, below the "For your information, There are..." text block.

Comment: b, i did... but no change ;( do i need to encrypt thing through the code ?

Comment: i mean, i was delete those line and download the gif to make it local but still error ;(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely because your page has links to non secure resources.

Taking a quick look at the source code:

```
<link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

These all link to non-secure resources. You will need to link them to secure resources for your page to not show that error you are getting.

Comment: i did... but no change ;( do i need to encrypt thing through the code ?

Comment: i mean, i was delete those line and download the gif to make it local but still error ;(

Comment: @Spencer - Are you sure, I just visited your site again in Chrome and no longer get the warning :)

Comment: Yea.. Thx ^^ i should restart my chrome earlier >.< keep trying but forgotten chrome like to cache the site XD